# Regular expression to match escaped sequences in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I am looking for regex to check for all escape sequences in java

```
\b  backspace
\t  horizontal tab
\n  linefeed
\f  form feed
\r  carriage return
\"  double quote
\'  single quote
\\  backslash
```

How do I write regex and perform validation to allow words / textarea / strings / sentences containing valid escape sequences

Comment: *"all escape sequences"* -- If `\'` qualifies as an escape sequence, then why not any other single character like: `\ `, `\p`, `\!`, ...? What about all the other special characters you've missed, such as `\a` and `\e`? What about hex and unicode escapes, such as `\x12`? And more importantly, **what are you actually trying to achieve here?**

Comment: I need to perform validation from data coming from TextArea entered from UI and need to pass thru if valid escape sequences are present. I need a regex for Java

Comment: If you want to make sure the text contains no backslashes unless they're part of one of those sequences, use this: `"\\A[^\\\\]*(?:\\\\[btnfr\"'\\\\][^\\\\]*)*\\z"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following regex should meet your need:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\[\\\\btnfr\'\"]");
```

as in

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\\\[\\\\btnfr\'\"]");
    String[] strings = new String[]{"\\b","\\t","\\n","\\f","\\r","\\\'","\\\"", "\\\\"};
    for (String s:strings) {
        System.out.println(s + " - " + pattern.matcher(s).matches());
    }
```

To match a single `\`, you would have to add 4 `\` inside a regex **string**.

Considering a string, `"\\"` stands for a single `\`.

When you have `"\\"` as a regex string, it means a `\` which is a special character in regex and it is supposed to be followed by certain other character to form an escape sequence.

In this way, we need `"\\\\"`, to match a single `\` which is equivalent to the string `"\\"`.

EDIT: There is no need to escape the single quote in the regex string. So `"\\\\[\\\\btnfr\'\"]"` can be replaced with `"\\\\[\\\\btnfr'\"]"`.

Comment: I have one requirement where \\` must not be allowed which is not valid escape sequences. How to check that. I have huge text area much bigger ones, cannot paste it here. like below to validate for escape sequences:

Comment: ___,------, 
             _,--.---.                         __,--'         / 
           ,' _,'_`._ \                    _,-'           ___,| 
          ;--'       `^-.                ,'        __,---'   || 
        ,'               \             ,'      _,-'          || 
       /                  \         _,'     ,-'              || 
      :

Comment: . . . . .. . . . . . . . . . . ,.-â€˜â€. . . . . . . . . .``~.,
. . . . . . . .. . . . . .,.-â€. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .â€œ-.,
. . . . .. . . . . . ..,/. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . â€:,
. . . . . . . .. .,?. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .\,
. . . . . . . . . /. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ,}
. . . . . . . . ./. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ,:`^`.}
. . . . . . . ./. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ,:â€. . . ./
. . . . . . .?. . . __. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :`

Comment: @Nikhil Hope that you need to check if there is a backslash not followed by any of the above said characters. Can you post it as a separate question and accept this one if it worked? Or update the question as required.

Comment: I have a requirement to validate huge text area and display error message if it contains invalid escape sequences and curly braces {} How do I achieve that exactly

Comment: Can you post it as a separate question with examples on which all are to be accepted and which all are to be rejected?

Answer (score 1):

This regex will match all your escape sequence that you have written:

```
\\[btnfr"'\\]
```

In Java you need to duplicate the backslash, the code will result as:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\\\[btnfr\\\"\\'\\\\]");
if(p.matcher("\\b  backspace").find()){
    System.out.println("Contains escape sequence");
}
```

Comment: With regexpal is working. Now I'll post the code for java

Comment: regexpal works awesome for Javascript. But same not working in Java  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[btnfr\"\'\\]"); Pls check

Comment: Just need `\"` and `'` respectively instead of `\\\"` and `\\'`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [DOTALL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) to match line terminators. You might also find `\s` handy as it represents all whitespace. Eg

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\s\"'\\]+)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher("foo '\r\n\t bar");
assertTrue(m.find());
assertEquals(" '\r\n\t ", m.group(1));
```

Comment: DOTALL only affects the behavior of the dot (`.`).  If the regex doesn't contain any dots, DOTALL has no effect.  Also, there should be four backslashes at the end of the class, not just two: `"([\\s\"'\\\\]+)"`.

Comment: I have a requirement to validate huge text area and display error message if it contains invalid escape sequences and curly braces {} How do I achieve that exactly